# How do I show a label instead of the value in a custom autocomplete?

Tags: forms

I am building a custom autocomplete field. It worked as in when I type 'a' it shows me all the list of fruits with letter 'a', but when I click on any of the options. I see the autocomplete field 'value'.

When users type *a*, it should show *Apple*, *Avocado*. Clicking on any of them, it should show *Apple*, not *fruit-1* in the field.

This is the code I am using.

#### Form

```
namespace Drupal\custom_google_search\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

class GoogleSearchAutocomplete extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'custom_google_search_autocomplete';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['google_places_search'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Searchfield'),
      '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'custom_google_search.autocomplete',
      '#value' => 'aaa11',
    ];
  $form['search_in_us'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Search'),
    ];
      return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }
}
```

#### Autocomplete controller

```
namespace Drupal\custom_google_search\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Tags;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;

class AutocompleteController extends ControllerBase {

  public function handleAutocomplete(Request $request) { 
    // Get the typed string from the URL, if it exists.
    if ($input = $request->query->get('q')) {
      $typed_string = Tags::explode($input);
      $typed_string = Unicode::strtolower(array_pop($typed_string));
      $trimed_string = preg_replace("/\s+/", "+", $typed_string);
      $results = $this->showRelatedPlaces($trimed_string);
    }
    return new JsonResponse($results);
  }

  public function showRelatedPlaces($trimed_string) {
    try {
       $results = [
         [
           'value' => 'fruit-1',
           'label' => 'Apples',
         ],
         [
           'value' => 'fruit-2',
           'label' => 'Apricots',
         ],
         [
           'value' => 'fruit-3',
           'label' => 'Avocados',
         ],
       ];

      return($results);

    } catch (RequestException $e) {
    return($this->t('Error occured.'));
  }
 }  
}
```

Problem is that when I type *a* in the autocomplete textfield, it shows the fruits label (*Apple*), but when I click on the fruit label, the field value shows *fruit-1*. I want to show *Apple* when users select *Apple*.

PS: I don't want to use the same value for label and value.

Comment: Make value and label the same: `$results = [['value' => 'Apples', 'label' => 'Apples'], ['value' => 'Apricots', 'label' => 'Apricots'], ['value' => 'Avocados', 'label' => 'Avocados']];`